# TableView refresh and textfields

Tags: uitableview, uitextfield, swift3, xcode8-beta6

I have a problem. In my app I have an embedded tableview. Tapping a button (first button) it is showed a view with a textfield and a button (second button).
I want that what I write in the textfield of the second view, pressing the second button, get saved in an array. Than what is saved should be printed in the tableView. Every time I press the second button the tableView should be refreshed, so can it shows the updated array.
How can do it?
Thanks everybody

Comment: Are all these views managed by the same view controller?  If not, how are the controllers related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After saving it into your array you should call function on your tableView. For example you have connected your table view with your ViewController via IBOutlet named tableview. Than just simply call this, when you want to refresh your tableview.

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

And that is all.